# How in django set in url unrequirement argument

Tags: django

All sense in title of query, i try this:

```
path(r'get_turnover/<str:attributes>/\?product=(?P<product>\w+$)', views.OutputTurnover.as_view(), name='get_turnover')
```

but it's not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is *not* part of the path. This is decoded by django and passed through `request.GET` as a [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) a dictionary-like object.

The path should thus be:

```
path(
    'get_turnover/<str:attributes>/',
    views.OutputTurnover.as_view(),
    name='get_turnover'
)
```

and in the view, you can access this with:

```
class OutputTurnover(View):

    def get(request, attributes):
        product = self.request.GET.get('product')
        # …
```

Comment: It's doen't work for me:
I do this
`    path(r'get_turnover//)', views.OutputTurnover.as_view(), name='get_turnover')`
 i try send this url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_turnover?page=30

and i get 404 error, django can't find the path,

Comment: @antipups: sorry, I made a typo.